# cuda trace emulation -Need some expert insight

Tags: cuda

I am working on a gpu trace emulation tool in windows as part of my research work in grad school . I am working on cuda runtime trace emulation to be specific.

I use simple DLL injection using MS Detours to enable interception of the cuda runtime APIs. I store the API calls and their parameters in a trace file. I get into some problems while trying to emulate the API from my trace file(I use the word playback to denote this action)

A typical trace file begins by making calls to __cudaRegisterFatBinary and __cudaRegisterFunction. This is followed by a call to cudaMalloc.

What I did?

1) I came across the famous GPUOcelot and I found the cubin structure that Nvidia is using right now. I am using that to save the address parameter of cudaRegisterFatBinary in intercept mode and I am using the pointer in the playback for _cudaRegisterFatBinary by repopulating the structure in the memory.

2)In _cudaRegisterFunction I am not sure what the parameters hostFunction,Device Function and Device Name refer to. I mean I don't understand how I could populate it while playing back from my trace file. I am just saving the pointer from the original execution and using it to imitate the call. But there is no way of knowing whether the function goes through fine since it does not have a return value.

3)cudaMalloc following these two entry point functions return cuda error code 11. It is cuda invalid value according to the Nvidia documentation. I have no idea why this should be the case. I am assuming that something is wrong with the previous two function calls. I also have a feeling that something is wrong with implicit primary context creation by the cuda runtime. Can someone give me some insights about cuda runtime execution and point me to what might I be missing?

I know its a ton of information without any useful code. I dont know which part of the code to post here. I will do it when people start taking interest in my question and ask me specific things about my project. Initially am just hoping that I am missing something big and high level that one of you can spot.

I greatly appreciate your time and interest!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds very interesting overall. Your "Error:Cuda invalid value" is could be related to the params of _cudaRegisterFunction. The param 'DeviceName' sounds like it identifies which GPU (card?) to use. Check the CUDA SDK, there are many demos that enumerate the GPUs on the system, perhaps these values are valid for 'DeviceName'. As for 'hostFunction' and 'deviceFunction', these sound like either function IDs, or perhaps function pointers. Also, you can call 'cudaGetLastError()' to test whether the function call was successful (it returns 'cudaSuccess' if everything is ok... take a look at the error logging macros in the sdk). Good luck!